# Tag data using matching keywords without using nested loops

Tags: python, pandas, regex, dataframe

I've been working on a problem for the past few days of which I am unable to solve. Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated. Basically I have a dataset containing free text called **mydata**. [Data](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11PW_fXeobiCE36R13boIus7p9F06h3GI/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=106913725106047598274&rtpof=true&sd=true)

```
   ID   Text
    1   my laptop broke down 3 days ago
    2   hello world, bye world
    3   my hot coffee has spilt over my mobile phone device and case containing a desktop
    4   I like cold fizzy water as well as hot healthy food recipes
    5   laptop and computer device is good
```

and another dataset called **L1L2 Tagging** [Data](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1mHAoy4tJIk834wPIyz3Sqi6fh9HmJuco/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=106913725106047598274&rtpof=true&sd=true)

```
L1 Category         L2 Category    Keyword1      &  Keyword2
electronics         computer       laptop       
electronics         computer       computer     
electronics         computer       mother        &  board
electronics         computer       desktop       &  case
electronics         smartphone     mobile        &  phone
electronics         smartphone     mobile        &  device
Food and Beverage   Snacks         healthy food  &  recipes
Food and Beverage   Drinks         cold          &  fizzy water
Food and Beverage   Drinks         hot           &  coffee
```

I would like to create new categories for mydata called 'L1 Category' and 'L2 Category' from the *L1L2 Tagging* file if both the Keyword1 and Keyword2 is present, or if Keyword1 is present alone (Keyword2 is NA). If there are multiple L1 and L2 categories, will create duplicate rows.

My current code although gives me the correct output, I would like to **avoid nested for loops** because my actual data is large and takes 5-6 hours to run. Any help or advice to avoid the additional for loop using regex is appreciated. Thanks!

```
import pandas as pd
import re

tag_l1l2 = pd.read_excel('/content/L1L2 Tagging.xlsx')
mydata = pd.read_excel('/content/mydata.xlsx')

mydata_duplicate = pd.DataFrame(columns=mydata.columns)

for i in range(len(mydata)):

  for j in range(len(tag_l1l2)):

    if re.search(r'\b' + re.escape(str(tag_l1l2['Keyword1'][j])) + r'\b', str(mydata['Text'][i]), flags=re.IGNORECASE) and re.search(r'\b' + re.escape(str(tag_l1l2['Keyword2'][j])) + r'\b', str(mydata['Text'][i]), flags=re.IGNORECASE) \
    or re.search(r'\b' + re.escape(str(tag_l1l2['Keyword1'][j])) + r'\b', str(mydata['Text'][i]), flags=re.IGNORECASE) and pd.isna(tag_l1l2['Keyword2'][j]):

      duplicate_df = mydata.iloc[[i]]
      duplicate_df['L1 Category'] = tag_l1l2['L1 Category'][j]
      duplicate_df['L2 Category'] = tag_l1l2['L2 Category'][j]

      mydata_duplicate = pd.concat([mydata_duplicate, duplicate_df], ignore_index=True)
      mydata_duplicate = mydata_duplicate.drop_duplicates()
```

**mydata_duplicate** (image as I cannot copy tables in):
[image]

Comment: It's clearly going to REQUIRE two nested loops to do this, because the problem requires it.  What you should ask yourself is whether pandas is buying you anything at all here.  You're not doing any numerical analysis, so why use pandas?  If you read those Excel files as CVS files, then you have a simple text search problem.  You could `.split` each line into a set and do quick `a in b` tests.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple script that uses those files as CSV files and does string searching.  It would not be hard to substitute one of the simple Excel file readers.

For my testing, I literally cut-and-pasted the values from your online Excel file, which led to tab-separated instead of comma-separated.  That's only a two-character change here.

```
# Read in the keyword maps.

maps=[]
for line in open('x2.csv'):
    parts = line.rstrip('\n').split(',')
    maps.append(parts)

# Read in the strings.

for line in open('x1.csv'):
    n,_,s = line.rstrip().partition(',')
    found = set()
    for m in maps:
        if m[2] in s and (not m[4] or m[4] in s):
            found.add( tuple(m[0:2]) )
    for m0,m1 in found:
        print( '\t'.join( (n, s, m0, m1)))
```

Output:

```
1,my laptop broke down 3 days ago,electronics,computer
3,my hot coffee has spilt over my mobile phone device and case containing a desktop,Food and Beverage,Drinks
3,my hot coffee has spilt over my mobile phone device and case containing a desktop,electronics,computer
3,my hot coffee has spilt over my mobile phone device and case containing a desktop,electronics,smartphone
4,I like cold fizzy water as well as hot healthy food recipes,Food and Beverage,Drinks
4,I like cold fizzy water as well as hot healthy food recipes,Food and Beverage,Snacks
5,laptop and computer device is good,electronics,computer
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```py
all_dfs = []
for k1, g in df2.groupby("Keyword1"):
    m1 = df1["Text"].str.contains(k1)
    masked_df = df1.loc[m1, ["ID", "Text"]]

    for l1, l2, k2 in zip(g["L1 Category"], g["L2 Category"], g["Keyword2"]):
        m2 = (
            [True] * len(masked_df)
            if pd.isna(k2)
            else masked_df["Text"].str.contains(k2)
        )

        d = masked_df[m2].copy()
        d["L1 Category"] = l1
        d["L2 Category"] = l2

        all_dfs.append(d)

out = pd.concat(all_dfs).drop_duplicates().sort_index()
print(out)
```

Prints:

```
   ID                                                                               Text        L1 Category L2 Category
0   1                                                    my laptop broke down 3 days ago        electronics    computer
2   3  my hot coffee has spilt over my mobile phone device and case containing a desktop        electronics    computer
2   3  my hot coffee has spilt over my mobile phone device and case containing a desktop  Food and Beverage      Drinks
2   3  my hot coffee has spilt over my mobile phone device and case containing a desktop        electronics  smartphone
3   4                        I like cold fizzy water as well as hot healthy food recipes  Food and Beverage      Drinks
3   4                        I like cold fizzy water as well as hot healthy food recipes  Food and Beverage      Snacks
4   5                                                 laptop and computer device is good        electronics    computer
```

---

Initial dataframes:

#### `df1`:

```
   ID                                                                               Text
0   1                                                    my laptop broke down 3 days ago
1   2                                                             hello world, bye world
2   3  my hot coffee has spilt over my mobile phone device and case containing a desktop
3   4                        I like cold fizzy water as well as hot healthy food recipes
4   5                                                 laptop and computer device is good
```

#### `df2`:

```
         L1 Category L2 Category      Keyword1     Keyword2
0        electronics    computer        laptop          NaN
1        electronics    computer      computer          NaN
2        electronics    computer        mother        board
3        electronics    computer       desktop         case
4        electronics  smartphone        mobile        phone
5        electronics  smartphone        mobile       device
6  Food and Beverage      Snacks  healthy food      recipes
7  Food and Beverage      Drinks          cold  fizzy water
8  Food and Beverage      Drinks           hot       coffee
```